# I have assets folder but not settings folder. Can I recreate unity3D project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, settings, recreate

so as the title says, I'm trying to recreate a unity3D project and the only thing I have is the Assets folder with the assets and their meta files.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Unity and select "Open Project" option and then select the Parent Folder of your Assets folder as the project and Unity will do the rest.